# How should I learn A country has states or not on Android Address?

Tags: android, geolocation, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I need to show an address like "City Name,Country Name".(Istanbul,Turkey)
But If that country has states like USA, my client wants from me to show this like "City Name, State Name" (Miami,Florida).

These fields get me names of areas.

```
String getAdminArea ()
Returns the administrative area name of the address, for example, "CA", or null if it is unknown

String getCountryCode ()
Returns the country code of the address, for example "US", or null if it is unknown.

String getLocality ()
Returns the locality of the address, for example "Mountain View", or null if it is unknown.
```

My Question is how can I control which county has states? Is the control that null checking locality correct way?

Answer (score 0):

[Geonames](http://www.geonames.org) has an api and a data dump of worldwide geographical places.

Comment: Does it have Country state control? I coundn't see at first look.